# Efficiently adding rows to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance

I'm trying to create a simple backtester on python which allows me to assess the performance of a trading strategy. As part of the backtester, I need to record the transactions which occur. E.g.,

```
Day     Stock    Action     Quantity
1       AAPL     BUY        20
2       CSCO     SELL       30
2       AMZN     SELL       50
```

During the trading simulation, I'll need to add more transactions.

What's the most efficient way to do this. Should I create a `transactions` list at the start of the simulation and append lists such as `[5, 'AAPL', 'BUY', 20]` as I go. Should I instead use a dictionary, or a numpy array? Or just a Pandas DataFrame directly?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: some sort of ? The question is what sort of ? Hows does the data from that sort of simulation look like?

Comment: More probably for a question like this answer usually would be it depends.

Comment: Just generic rows of data. One row might contain the values `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, for instance.

Comment: you cant ask for opinions here. As a data science question we like to see the data and type of operation you want to perform on the data. This is too broad.

Comment: Afaik, `numpy` copies the whole array, if you add a row. So for numpy to work well, it is preferable to create a numpy array of the maximum size and fill in data.

Comment: As @Dark mentioned...it depends !

Comment: Okay, thanks for comments. I'll update my question.

Comment: Use a list. Append operations are very costly in numpy and pandas. Convert to a DataFrame once you are done.

Comment: Define "most efficient"...

Comment: I'm assuming the simulation will take more time than anything else anyway, so why not just write out lines to a .csv file instead? Anything that works in-memory runs the risk of out-of-memory if the number of simulations is huge

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers fastest and most pythonic.

Comment: +1 for making a numpy array (perhaps a [`np.recarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html)) of large size and write your rows to it. A record array has the advantage that you can quickly convert your data to a Pandas dataframe afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.append` operations are [amortised constant time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) operations, because it just involves shifting pointers around.

OTOH, `numpy.ndarray` and `pd.DataFrame` objects are internally represented as arrays in C, and those are immutable. Each time you "append" to an array/dataframe, you have to *reallocate* new memory for an entire copy of the old data plus the appended, and ends up being linear in complexity.

So, as @ayhan said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300891/most-efficient-way-to-store-rows-of-data-in-python/48301196?noredirect=1#comment83586577_48300891), accumulate your data in a `list`, and then load into a dataframe once you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your help!